# Ardunio Serial Monitor printing characters 0,1 before printing characters 0,1,2,etc

Tags: c#, printing, arduino

I'm using very simple ardunio code to print "hello world." just once. But when it prints to the serial monitor, the characters "hehello world." appear.  Does anyone know why the "he" is getting printed twice?

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
Serial.print("hello");
 delay(1000);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print("world.");
  delay(1000);
Serial.print("  ");  
  delay(1000);
while(1) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but a few possibilities:

- For one, this code will start running as soon as the Arduino is powered, but it won't output to the Serial Monitor until you tell it to. So the "hello" is likely already written by the time you open it. You can solve this by putting in a long delay for the "hello" command or after `Serial.begin()`.
- Another thought: the `delay()` may be interfering with the serial writing. Writing to serial takes a certain length of time, and when the code reaches the `delay()` call, it may still be in the middle of writing "hello". You can solve this by using a function other than `delay()`. For example, have a variable called `startTime`, which gets initiated to `millis()` during `setup()`. Then say(for example):

  ```
  if (millis()>startTime+1000 && !helloSent){
    Serial.print("hello");
    helloSent=true;
  }
  ```

And then get rid of your `while` loop.

Neither of these really account for "hehello" (if anything, I'd expect you to see "llo" or some such). But they're thoughts.

Silly obvious thing: make sure the baud rate on your Serial Monitor actually matches up to 9600